# Why __enter__ should not be called on the superclass/delegate?

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

I'm working on an [exercise](https://exercism.org/tracks/python/exercises/paasio) that asks to wrap network operations in two different ways, subclassing, and delegation, respectively. Snippets of my code are shown below.

```
class MeteredFile(io.BufferedRandom):
    """Implement using a subclassing model."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._read_bytes = self._write_bytes = self._read_ops = self._write_ops = 0

    def __enter__(self) -> Self:
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type: Type[BaseException] | None,
                 exc_val: BaseException | None, exc_tb: TracebackType | None) -> bool | None:
        return super().__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

    # Other methods not shown
```

```
class MeteredSocket:
    """Implement using a delegation model."""

    def __init__(self, s: socket):
        self._socket = s
        self._recv_bytes = self._send_bytes = self._recv_ops = self._send_ops = 0

    def __enter__(self) -> Self:
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type: Type[BaseException] | None,
                 exc_val: BaseException | None, exc_tb: TracebackType | None) -> bool | None:
        return self._socket.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

    # Other methods not shown
```

If I call `super().__enter__()` from `MeteredFile.__enter__` or  `self._socket.__enter__()` from `MeteredSocket.__enter__` , some tests fail, as those do *not* expect those methods to be called. Returning `self` keeps those tests happy.

```
@patch("paasio.super", create=True, new_callable=SuperMock)
def test_meteredfile_context_manager(self, super_mock):
    wrapped = MockFile(ZEN)
    mock = NonCallableMagicMock(wraps=wrapped, autospec=True)
    mock.__exit__.side_effect = wrapped.__exit__
    super_mock.mock_object = mock
    with MeteredFile() as file:
        self.assertEqual(1, super_mock.init_called)
        self.assertFalse(mock.__enter__.called)
        file.read()
    self.assertFalse(mock.__enter__.called)
    mock.__exit__.assert_called_once_with(None, None, None)
    self.assertEqual(2, len(mock.mock_calls))
    with self.assertRaisesRegex(ValueError, "I/O operation on closed file."):
        file.read()
    with self.assertRaisesRegex(ValueError, "I/O operation on closed file."):
        file.write(b"data")

@patch("paasio.super", create=True, new_callable=SuperMock)
def test_meteredfile_context_manager_exception_raise(self, super_mock):
    exception = MockException("Should raise")
    wrapped = MockFile(ZEN, exception=exception)
    mock = NonCallableMagicMock(wraps=wrapped, autospec=True)
    mock.__exit__.side_effect = wrapped.__exit__
    super_mock.mock_object = mock
    with self.assertRaisesRegex(MockException, "Should raise") as err:
        with MeteredFile() as file:
            self.assertFalse(mock.__enter__.called)
            file.read()
    self.assertFalse(mock.__enter__.called)
    mock.__exit__.assert_called_once_with(
        MockException,
        err.exception,
        ANY,
    )
    self.assertEqual(exception, err.exception)
```

However, the `__exit__` methods are called as expected. I don't understand why this difference, can someone explain?

Comment: Can you see the code of the failing tests?

Comment: @slothrop Yes, I can, updated the post to add couple of them.

Comment: Thanks! Assuming `paasio` is the name of the module containing your classes, it looks like the tests are specifically designed to fail if the superclass's `__enter__` is called (`super` is patched to return a mock object, and then `self.assertFalse(mock.__enter__.called)` fails on a call to `super().__enter__()`.) **Why** the tests do that probably depends what was in the mind of the creator of the exercise...

Comment: @slothrop “_the tests are specifically designed to fail if the superclass's `__enter__` is called_” yes, that’s what my question says. I’d like to know if there’s a design principle behind this choice. For example, returning `self` instead of the superclass is a design choice that enables method calls to be chained.

Comment: Aha, sorry, I didn't read *"do not expect those methods to be called"* as synonymous with *"are specifically designed to fail if those methods are called"*. I too don't see the rationale for this choice.

Comment: In general subclasses should call the superclass implementation unless there is a reason for it. In this case if you just call `super().__enter__/__exit__` you end up with classes that literally do nothing since all their methods would simply be delegating to the parent implementation, so I guess the author wants you to re-write the logic to close the file/socket in `__exit__` and open it in `__enter__`